# Representation of a group using Cayley's table

Tags: abstract-algebra

How would do you describe the group $(\mathbb{Z_{5}^{*}}, {\cdot_5})$  using Cayley's table?

Comment: It's cyclic and generated by $2$ and $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we write the elements of the group along the top and left.
$$\begin{matrix} &\cdot_5 &1 &2 &3 &4 \\ &1 &? &? &? &? \\ &2 &? &? &? &? \\ &3 &? &? &? &? \\ &4 &? &? &? &? \end{matrix}$$

Now we just need to fill in the middle. This shouldn't be too difficult. For example, $2\cdot_5 3 = 1$ (since $2\times 3 = 6 \equiv 1$ mod $5$). We then fill in the element in the $2$ row and $3$ column:

$$\begin{matrix} &\cdot_5 &1 &2 &3 &4 \\ &1 &? &? &? &? \\ &2 &? &? &1 &? \\ &3 &? &? &? &? \\ &4 &? &? &? &? \end{matrix}$$

This can go faster by recognizing that the operation is commutative.

Comment: Why $\mathbb{Z_5^{*}}\neq \{0,1,2,3,4\}$?

Comment: @user300044 Sorry for the late response. If I understand the notation, $\mathbb Z^*_p$ generally does not contain the zero element. If $0$ were included, then it would not be a group (there is no inverse for $0$).